# Javascript: Firefox prefmanager

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to code an extension to Firefox for the first time and I have a problem with the prefmanager.

```
var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var updateintervall =   prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.traffic.updateintervall");
```

After the second line of Javascript code my extension seems to stop working. The following codelines won't be excecuted anymore... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has been a while, but that worked for me. It could be that the call to prefManager.getCharPref throws an exception. Put a try/catch around your code and check what the exception tells you.

Answer (score 0):

The `nsIPref*` API expects preferences to already exist when using the `get*()` functions. When trying to get a preference that does not and exception will be thrown.
Also, the API may throw if you try to read e.g. an existing numerical preference as a string.
You can try/catch exceptions of course.

You might want to add [`default preferences`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Preferences#Default_preferences) to your XUL-based add-on, to not having to try/catch for non-existing prefs.

SDK users should have a look at the [`simple-prefs`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html) and/or [`preferences/service`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/preferences/service.html) APIs.

Aside: These days you'll want to use the cached [`Services.prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) to access `nsIPref*`.